# Контроль анимации

Tags: unity3d, анимация

Вопрос по поводу анимации, итак стоит галочка "Apply Root Motion" в одной анимации удара, персонаж переносится вперёд, как сделать, что бы на конкретной анимации эта функция не действовала, скрипт какой или настройки?